# How to read firebase realtime database to flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to make some IoT App (without sign in). The App is reading sensor data from the Firebase realtime database. the database shown below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xspUr.png)

I want some function to read the value of current and power then convert it into a float value on the flutter app.

Comment: Did you see https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/flutter/read-and-write#read_data?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to describe more detail for your question. In case you have a flutter app and now you want to integrate firebase to this app and using firebase database, you can follow [this firebase document.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=android)

After successfully add firebase and firebase_database to your app, you can use firebase API and `StreamBuilder` to retrive and display your data snapshot. Like this

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(          
    stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('sensor').snapshots(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if(snapshot.hasData) return CircularProgressIndicator();

        if(snapshot.hasData) return Container(
            /// Display your sensor data
        )
    }
)
```